# Opencv 2.4.11 Java: Drawing lines from center of mass to edge of contour

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction

Basically , I have a binary image that contains an object , I applied contours and moments functions to find the center of mass , and detect the object in this image . ( irregular object )

What I want to do now is to generate lines ( at different angles ) passing through the center of mass , to the edge of the contour , and find which line is of the longest length .

Any help regarding this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the lines are drawn from the center of mass to the perimeter of the mass, instead of using test angles just use the contour points themselves and perform a distance calculation on each set of points. See below for example.
(The example code is in C++ and the question tag is java, I will get burned one day for this.)

```
    Mat GrayImage; // input grayscale image, set to something
    Mat ContourImage;
    Mat DrawImage = Mat::zeros(GrayImage.size(), CV_8UC3);
    int thresh = 90;
    // get a threshold image using Canny edge detector
    Canny(GrayImage, ContourImage, thresh, thresh * 2, 3);
    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(ContourImage, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);// retrieves external contours, CHANGES THRESHOLD IMAGE   

    vector<Point2f> centerofMass(contours.size());
    vector<Moments> mu(contours.size());
    // for every contour in the image
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        // draw the contour
        drawContours(DrawImage, contours, i, Scalar(200, 54, 120), 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
        //calculate center of mass
        mu[i] = moments(contours[i],false);
        centerofMass[i] = Point2f(mu[i].m10 / mu[i].m00, mu[i].m01 / mu[i].m00);

        double biggestDistance = 0;
        Point2f farthest_Perimeter_Point;
        // for each point in the current contour
        for (int j = 0; j < contours[i].size(); j++)
        {
            // get a point that makes up the contour
            Point2f perimeterofMass(contours[i][j].x, contours[i][j].y);
            //calculate the distance
            double dist = cv::norm(centerofMass[i] - perimeterofMass);
            // determine farthest point
            if (dist > biggestDistance)
            {
                biggestDistance = dist;
                farthest_Perimeter_Point = perimeterofMass;
            }
        }
        // now we have farthest point as farthest_Perimeter_Point for the current contour at [i]
        //draw the line because why not;
        line(DrawImage, centerofMass[i], farthest_Perimeter_Point, Scalar(145, 123, 201));
    }
    imshow("grayimage", GrayImage);
    imshow("thresholdimage", ContourImage);
    imshow("drawimage", DrawImage);
```

The other assumption would be the lines are drawn from one starting point on the mass's perimeter to the other side of the mass while intersecting the center. First start with one point of the perimeter, form line equation in [point-intercept form](http://www.sparknotes.com/math/algebra1/writingequations/section1.rhtml) using the start point and the center point. Second find where this line intersects the other side and now you can calculate distance. Third determine the largest distance among these lines.

References:

[Related OpenCV question](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14188/calc-eucliadian-distance-between-two-single-point/)

[Related OpenCV example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html)

Comment: I guess the code written up is getting half the distance ( from center to a point on the contour ) , and that doesn't fulfill the required since the object is irregular .
Your other assumption is exactly what i need to do , but i can't find any function that would extract the points .
Thank you for your input